# Why row height is squeezing after scroll for tableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I am using a tableView and with the tableView I am using a label and my requirement is to make the label auto-adjusting according to the text. So I am calculating dynamic height for my label. It is working fine initially but after scroll the height of the label is reduced. I don't know why.

```
// to calculate dynamic height of the label
    func height(constraintedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let label =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.text = self
        label.font = font
        label.sizeToFit()

        return label.frame.height
     }
```

Comment: Please add code for a minimal reproducible example, the provided code snippet is not enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a cell reuse issue, but without the `cellForRowAt` and cell class it's hard to say more.

Comment: If you use auto-layout, there is no need to calculate heights -- it's all done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try!

```
extension UILabel {
func textWidth() -> CGFloat {
    return UILabel.textWidth(label: self)
}

func textHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return UILabel.textHeight(withWidth: self.frame.width, font: self.font, text: self.text ?? "")
}

class func textWidth(label: UILabel) -> CGFloat {
    return textWidth(label: label, text: label.text!)
}

class func textWidth(label: UILabel, text: String) -> CGFloat {
    return textWidth(font: label.font, text: text)
}

class func textWidth(font: UIFont, text: String) -> CGFloat {
    return textSize(font: font, text: text).width
}

class func textHeight(withWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont, text: String) -> CGFloat {
    return textSize(font: font, text: text, width: width).height
}

class func textSize(font: UIFont, text: String, extra: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = textSize(font: font, text: text)
    size.width = size.width + extra.width
    size.height = size.height + extra.height
    return size
}

class func textSize(font: UIFont, text: String, width: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude) -> CGSize {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.size
}

class func countLines(font: UIFont, text: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude) -> Int {
    // Call self.layoutIfNeeded() if your view uses auto layout
    let myText = text as NSString

    let rect = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

    return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / font.lineHeight))
}

func countLines(width: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude) -> Int {
    // Call self.layoutIfNeeded() if your view uses auto layout
    let myText = (self.text ?? "") as NSString

    let rect = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.font], context: nil)

    return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / self.font.lineHeight))
}
}
```